# PHP Counter Getting One Month Higher Than Expected

Tags: php

I'm building a relationship counter for a profile as to how long someone has been in a relationship or single.

The counter works, but it is giving me one month above what it should be.

The PHP is:

```
<?php
 function relationshipTime($relationshipDate) {
     date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");
     $relationshipStart = $relationshipDate;
     $todaysDate = date("m/d/Y");
     $diff = abs(strtotime($todaysDate) - strtotime($relationshipStart));
     $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     $months = ceil(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
     $months2 = floor(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
     $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months2 * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24)/ (60 * 60 * 24));
     echo $years . " Years " . $months . " Months " . $days . " Days ";
}
?>
```

And then:

```
<?php relationshipTime("05/25/2015"); echo "Single"; ?>
```

Which outputs:

```
0 Years 1 Months 20 Days Single
```

But 5/25/2015 hasn't even been a month ago yet.

What would be causing this to be almost 40 days ahead?

Comment: You'd save yourself and the interpreter, for that matter, a lot of (unnecessary) work if you'd start using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$months = floor(($diff - ($years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / ((365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 12));
```

Replace the `$months` ceil with floor.